# how to a search a value in column of excel sheet using selection.find?

Tags: excel, vba, search

I want to search a value in a particular column of an Excel sheet and after that insert one new row. Like in the first column, search for "application 1" and after that add one extra row after "applicationone".

```
Application Program Variable    
Application_1   Program1    
Application_1   Program1    
Application_1   Program1    
Application_2   Program1    
Application_2   Program1
```

I am trying to search with the following code:

```
.Activate 
.Columns("B:B").Select

     Selection.Find(What:="Application_1", After:=ActiveCell, LookIn:=xlValues, _
        LookAt:=xlWhole, SearchOrder:=xlByRows, SearchDirection:=xlNext, _
        MatchCase:=False).Activate
```

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: can you show more code please? are you getting any errors?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your code looks fine

After that to insert a new row you can just

```
ActiveCell.Offset(1).EntireRow.Insert
```

And then

```
ActiveCell.Offset(1).Value="What ever you want"
```